# Trading View tvWidget,setSymbol not working if i trigger it 2 times for same symbol

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

i'm new to trading view and trying to achieve an function in which it takes the same symbol but with different lot size and will calculate the data based on the lots but when i'm trying to trigger the setSymbol function twice with the lots request is not going

```
if (window.tvWidget) {      
window.tvWidget.onChartReady(function() {
// console.log("1: ", tvWidget.clearUndoHistory());
tvWidget.setSymbol(symbol, '1', function() {
console.log("Done");
});
});
```

I'm trying to achieve a new data request to my getData file